# Can't download laravel/homestead vagrant box

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'm currently trying to install the Homestead Vagrant box but I can't get it to finish the download. It starts but then stops part way through.

When I try "vagrant box add laravel/homestead" I get the following error:

```
`The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/homestead"]
Error: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to vagrantcloud.com:443 `
```

I have also tried to download manually at https://atlas.hashicorp.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/4.0.0/providers/virtualbox.box but the download speed drops to 0 B/s and never completes. I have tried http and https. Nothing seems to be working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: have you installed vagrant and virtual box?

Comment: Check [The box 'laravel/homestead' could not be found](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/the-box-laravelhomestead-could-not-be-found?page=1)

Comment: [Homestead installation issues](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/homestead-installation-issues)